# I have two tables I want to retrieve the different results from same column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have listed the actual table. From that I want the result as expected one.

[image]

Comment: what are the 2 tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not that you have written in your problem. You first go to learn how to normalize the SQL or Tabular data. When you apply the second normal form this issue is resolved. 
The given link provides a better understanding of normalization.
[Normalization in SQL Tables](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
jobPreference varchar(255),
Triggered varchar(255),
Success varchar(255),
opened varchar(255));


INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('email-pwd reset', 'yes', 'success','yes');
INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('email-pwd reset', 'yes', 'success','yes');

INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('email-pwd reset', 'yes', 'fail','no');
INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('email-statement', 'yes', 'success','no');
INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('email-EMI reminder', 'yes', 'fail','no');
INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('SMS-loan EMI', 'yes', 'fail','no');
INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('SMS-confirmation', 'yes', 'fail','no');
INSERT INTO demo(jobPreference,Triggered,Success,opened) VALUES ('SMS-confirmation', 'yes', 'success','yes');


select SUBSTRING(jobPreference,0,CHARINDEX('-',jobPreference,0)) as Splitted
        ,jobPreference
        ,count(case Triggered when 'yes' then 1 else null end) as TriggeredCount
        ,count(case Success when 'success' then 1 else null end) as SuccessCount
        ,count(case opened when 'yes' then 1 else null end) as openedCount 
from demo
group by jobPreference
```

For demo : https://rextester.com/ANPN26483